# Unselect highlighted row

Tags: javascript

I have this table, and I can't seem to find out how to `unselect` marked field, if it's clicked again? So a double-click on `id 2` would `select->unselect`.

```js
function highlight_row() {
    var table = document.getElementById('testresultsTable');
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');  
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        // Take each cell
        var cell = cells[i];
        // do something on onclick event for cell
        cell.onclick = function () {
            // Get the row id where the cell exists
            var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
            var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
                rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
                rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
            }
            var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId];
            rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            rowSelected.className += " selected";    
        }
    }
  
  } //end of function
  window.onload = highlight_row;
```

```html
<table id="testresultsTable">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Tests</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>TESTRUN1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>TESTRUN2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>TESTRUN3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I thought about making some kind of count on the `rowID`, so if it's clicked more than once after each other, then it would toggle between `select/unselect`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by doing something similar to this, this will first check the selected row for the `selected` class and remove it if it is found, otherwise, it'll add it to the row you clicked. After that is done, this function will loop through all other rows, check if they aren't the clicked row and remove the selected state accordingly.

So now once you click, your code will look for `selected` on the row you clicked, if it is found, it'll remove that class to reset the styling, if it isn't found, it'll add the `selected` class. After this, the code will check all rows to see if they're not the selected row and style them accordingly.

```js
function highlight_row() {
  var table = document.getElementById('testresultsTable');
  var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    // Take each cell
    var cell = cells[i];
    // do something on onclick event for cell
    cell.onclick = function() {
      // Get the row id where the cell exists
      
      var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
      var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
      for (var row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
        if(row !== rowId) {
          rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
          rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
        }
      }
      var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId];
      if (rowSelected.classList.contains('selected')) {
          rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "";
          rowSelected.classList.remove('selected');
      } else {
        rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        rowSelected.classList.add("selected");
      }
      
    }
  }

} //end of function
window.onload = highlight_row;
```

```html
<table id="testresultsTable">
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Tests</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>TESTRUN1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>TESTRUN2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>TESTRUN3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @kooskoos No I did not, we must've been writing it at the same time.

Comment: It is indeed, because I noticed I made a mistake in the order of the code, so I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
function highlight_row() {
    var table = document.getElementById('testresultsTable');
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');  
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        // Take each cell
        var cell = cells[i];
        // do something on onclick event for cell
        cell.onclick = function () {
            // Get the row id where the cell exists
            var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
            var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
                if(row!==rowId){
                   rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "white";
                   rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
               }
            }
            var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId];
            
        if(rowSelected.classList.contains("selected")) {
           rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "";
           rowSelected.classList.remove("selected");
        } 
        else{
           rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
           rowSelected.classList.add("selected");
         }
  
        }
    }
  
  } //end of function
  window.onload = highlight_row;
```

```html
<table id="testresultsTable">
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Tests</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>TESTRUN1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>TESTRUN2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>TESTRUN3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But when the marked field is clicked again it doesn't unselect it?

Comment: Check the code, and let me know if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

**I'd do it like this**

```js
var selected;
(function () {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#testresultsTable > tbody > tr'); 
  rows.forEach(tr => tr.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(selected === tr){
      selected.classList.remove('selected');
      selected = undefined;
    }
    else {
      if(selected) selected.classList.remove('selected');
      selected = tr;
      tr.classList.add('selected');
    }
  }));
})();
```

```css
tbody > tr {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
tr.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="testresultsTable">
    <thead><th>ID</th><th>Tests</th></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>TESTRUN1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>TESTRUN2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>TESTRUN3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```